# Tensorflow, How can I restore model when some new layers are added?

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a model and save the checkpoints. The code of my model is:

```py
with tf.variable_scope(scope):
    self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 80, 80, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
    self.conv_1 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.inputs, num_outputs=32,
                              kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    self.conv_2 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_1, num_outputs=64,
                              kernel_size=[4, 4], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    self.conv_3 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_2, num_outputs=64,
                              kernel_size=[3, 3], stride=1, padding='SAME')
    self.fc = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(self.conv_3), 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)

    # Output layers for policy and value estimations
    self.policy = slim.fully_connected(self.fc,
                                       cfg.ACTION_DIM,
                                       activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
                                       biases_initializer=None)
    self.value = slim.fully_connected(self.fc,
                                      1,
                                      activation_fn=None,
                                      biases_initializer=None)
```

There are about 32 processes running simultaneously and each has a copy of the global network defined in the above code, the `scope` is the id of each process. The `scope` of global network is `global`.

And after that, I want to add more layers after `self.fc` layer.

```py
with tf.variable_scope(scope):
    self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 80, 80, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
    self.conv_1 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.inputs, num_outputs=32,
                              kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    self.conv_2 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_1, num_outputs=64,
                              kernel_size=[4, 4], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    self.conv_3 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_2, num_outputs=64,
                              kernel_size=[3, 3], stride=1, padding='SAME')
    self.fc = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(self.conv_3), 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)

    # Output layers for policy and value estimations
    self.policy = slim.fully_connected(self.fc,
                                       cfg.ACTION_DIM,
                                       activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,
                                       biases_initializer=None)
    self.value = slim.fully_connected(self.fc,
                                      1,
                                      activation_fn=None,
                                      biases_initializer=None)

    self.new_fc_1 = slim.fully_connected(self.fc, 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)
```

However, when I restore the model, it reported the following error:

```
2017-08-03 22:23:43.473157: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key worker_15/fully_connected_3/weights not found in checkpoint
2017-08-03 22:23:43.477197: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Data loss: Checksum does not match: stored 379803423 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 2648422677
2017-08-03 22:23:43.477210: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Data loss: Checksum does not match: stored 3963326522 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 3154501583
2017-08-03 22:23:43.477200: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Data loss: Checksum does not match: stored 3893236466 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 1767411214
2017-08-03 22:23:43.478276: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Data loss: Checksum does not match: stored 4239176201 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 3213118706
2017-08-03 22:23:43.480438: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Data loss: Checksum does not match: stored 442335910 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 4248164641
2017-08-03 22:23:43.483885: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Data loss: Checksum does not match: stored 3105262865 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 2648422677
2017-08-03 22:23:43.483953: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key worker_15/fully_connected_3/weights not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_128 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_128/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_128/shape_and_slices)]]
2017-08-03 22:23:43.486987: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key worker_15/fully_connected_3/weights not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_128 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_128/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_128/shape_and_slices)]]
2017-08-03 22:23:43.490616: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key worker_15/fully_connected_3/weights not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_128 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_128/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_128/shape_and_slices)]]
2017-08-03 22:23:43.491951: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key worker_15/fully_connected_3/weights not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_128 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_128/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_128/shape_and_slices)]]
2017-08-03 22:23:43.491957: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key worker_15/fully_connected_3/weights not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_128 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_128/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_128/shape_and_slices)]]
2017-08-03 22:23:43.494310: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key worker_15/fully_connected_3/weights not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_128 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_128/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_128/shape_and_slices)]]
.... ....
```

I used the following code to save model

```py
saver.save(sess, self.model_path+'/model-'+str(episode_count)+'.ckpt')
```

And here is the code to define saver

```py
value_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/old_scope')
value_list.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/actor_critic'))
saver = tf.train.Saver(value_list, max_to_keep=100)

with tf.Session(config=tf_configs) as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    if load_model:
        print('Loading Model...')
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_path)
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    else:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

How can I restore a pre-trained model when some new layers with random initialized parameters are added to the current neural network?

Comment: Use the old model to restore the checkpoint and add the new tensors afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for a long time and with the help of @BlueSun, I found the following method can help to solve this problem.

First use variables from current scopes to save models before adding new scope.

```py
value_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/old_scope')
value_list.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/actor_critic'))
saver = tf.train.Saver(value_list, max_to_keep=100)
```

And to train the newtwork.

Later, adding the new scope and define a new `saver` before running the model, code like this

```py
value_list = []
value_list.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/old_scope'))
value_list.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/actor_critic'))
value_list.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/added_layer'))
saver = tf.train.Saver(value_list, max_to_keep=100)

with tf.Session(config=tf_configs) as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    if load_model:
        print('Loading Model...')
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_path)
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    else:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="global"), max_to_keep=100)
```

and the network code looks like this

```py
with tf.variable_scope(scope):
    with tf.variable_scope('old_scope'):
        self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 80, 80, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
        self.conv_1 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.inputs, num_outputs=32,
                                  kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=4, padding='SAME')
        self.conv_2 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_1, num_outputs=64,
                                  kernel_size=[4, 4], stride=2, padding='SAME')
        self.conv_3 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, inputs=self.conv_2, num_outputs=64,
                                  kernel_size=[3, 3], stride=1, padding='SAME')
        self.fc = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(self.conv_3), 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)

    with tf.variable_scope('added_layer'):
        self.fc_1 = slim.fully_connected(self.fc, 512, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)

    with tf.variable_scope('actor_critic'):
        # Output layers for policy and value estimations
        self.policy = slim.fully_connected(self.fc_1,
                                         cfg.ACTION_DIM,
                                         activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax, 
                                         biases_initializer=None)
        self.value = slim.fully_connected(self.fc_1,
                                          1,
                                          activation_fn=None,
                                          biases_initializer=None)
```

It works fine now, although the code looks a bit unelegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two separate variable scopes. One for saving and loading and one for new layers.

Then you can specify the saver to only work with the variables from the first scope:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(
    tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="save_scope")
)
```

Comment: Could you provide more examples?

Comment: `value_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/old_scope')
value_list.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/actor_critic'))
value_list.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='global/added_layer'))
saver = tf.train.Saver(value_list, max_to_keep=100)` I added a new layer and later when I restore the model, it reported **Key global/added_layer/fully_connected/weights not found in checkpoint**

Comment: Is the new layer part of the 'global/added_layer' scope? If yes, why do you extend your value_list with the added_layer scope? You must initialize the Saver using only the scopes with the old layers which you try to load, like `saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="old_scope"), max_to_keep=100)`. Otherwise the Saver will try to load layers that didn't exist before.

Comment: If you also want to save snapshots of all layers later, then just define multiple tf.train.Saver. One only for loading the previous layers with the restricted scope, and one for saving with all variables.